# Run a method after 5 minutes of creation of record in model rails

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, delayed-job

I'm new to rails,

If I send a request to any user and in case if there is not any response from there with in 5 minutes then request send to another user.

How can I do this in **rails** please suggest me.

Comment: Sorry, it is not clear with the above description. Please explain in detail. Are you trying to send a friend request kind of thing to user and wait for 5 mins for them to respond or is it something else?

Comment: Yes Something like same.. Actually I want to send a request and wait for 5 minutes if request is not accepted by that user then second user will receive a request and again wait for 5 minutes

Comment: You probably need a background process to be kicked off 5 mins after the initial "request" is created, you could use sidekiq: https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq/wiki/Scheduled-Jobs

Comment: Exactly, I too would suggest having some background processor like sidekiq and schedule a task using "perform_at" when the method is called and once you get the response from the user, you can find the job with id and cancel the scheduled job or the job will get executed after 5 mins and you can skip the previous user while sending the request to other by having status to the requested user.

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of **run_at** option provided by delayed job.

```
class RecordModel < ActiveRecord::Base
   after_create :make_delayed_entry

   def make_delayed_entry
      Delayed::Job.enqueue(SendMailAndWaitJob.new(parameters), 0, 5.minutes.from_now, :queue => "queue_name")
   end
end
```

**SendMailAndWaitJob** its the class file(lib file) where you can check request accepted or not.

Comment: should I need to run any other server for this like redis, sidekiq